# Can't read process output with cat and tail

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a simple example of writing to `stdout`:

```
import datetime
import time


if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:
        print('time is {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().time()))
        time.sleep(5)
```

Then I did:

```
python main.py & echo $!
```

to run my process and get its PID.

My purpose is reading from `stdout` of my current process above, but all of these commands just freeze console and don't show `stdout` content

```
sudo tail -f /proc/15608/fd/1my console
sudo cat /proc/15608/fd/1
```

Notice `strace` works perfectly:

```
sudo strace -e write=1 -e trace=write -p 15608
```

But it gives me too much useless text.

My question: why don't `cat` (and `tail`) work properly and freeze my console? Could somebody explain me why it happens?

Comment: This might answer some of your questions: [Why can't I `tail -f /proc/$pid/fd/1`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152773/why-cant-i-tail-f-proc-pid-fd-1)